# Remove Recently Viewed Products in RWD Theme using local.xml

Tags: layout, local.xml, rwd

I am trying to remove the Recently Viewed Products from sidebar on the new RWD Theme. Please see my local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I have managed to remove the compare sidebar but not the recently viewed. I have manage to do it on the other themes but not on the RWD. I have also checked all the xml files in the layout folder for RWD for the words viewed and reports and nothing comes back. So I get its reverting back to BASE but then if that was the case should the above xml code remove the recently viewed?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I figured this out its actually

> **name="left.reports.product.viewed"**

```
not the
```

> *name="right.reports.product.viewed"*

even though it is being displayed in the right column.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
            <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

if you want to remove any of the block, then you have to specified where you want to remove `right, left, content`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just tried this and the block is still there :D. I also tried inside of: <catalog_category_view> instead of <default> and also <cms_page>. Its very strange, cache is disabled also.

Comment: You do not have to specify where you want to remove it. You can simple put it into the layout handle and it will be removed from all blocks.